# Dell Inspiron 13 laptop speaker constant hiss

Tags: sound, dell, speakers

I have a Dell Inspiron 13 7348 laptop and in Ubuntu the speakers emit a constant hissing sound with an occasional click. The sound starts at the lightdm login screen. There is no hiss in Windows so this seems a specific problem to Ubuntu. Anyone have any ideas how to stop this?
From reading around I've read a few suggestions to lower mic boost in alsamixer but i've tried this and its made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found a solution so I'm answering my own question! It might help someone else if they're struggling anyway.
So heres what I did. I ran `lsmod` in a Terminal and saw that there were 3 different codecs in use:

- `snd_hda_codec_generic`
- `snd_hda_codec_hdmi`
- `snd_hda_codec_realtek`

I have no idea if this is normal but I thought maybe they have something to do with it so I blacklisted them all in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (by adding blacklist `snd_hda_codec_xxxx` at the end of the file). I also blacklisted `snd_hda_intel` just in case that was the culprit.

I then rebooted and the hissing sound was gone but so was all sound (guessing this is because of blacklisting `snd_hda_intel`).

So next step was to start unblacklisting the various things 1 by 1. First I unblacklisted `snd_hda_intel` and the hissing was still gone but the sound was back to normal!

Interestingly, even with the other 3 codecs blacklisted `snd_hda_codec_generic` and `snd_hda_codec_hdmi` still show up in `lsmod`. Is this because they're codecs and modules?

Anyway there is no `snd_hda_codec_realtek` showing so im guessing this might have been the cause of the hissing. So far I have not faced any other sound related problems so I'm not sure why `snd_hda_codec_realtek` was loaded but its all working so I'll leave it this way unless someone offers a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Try ***alsamixer*** from command line.
Press **F4** (capture)
Use left or right arrow key to highlight "***Mic Boost***".
Use up/down arrow keys to adjust sound so that hiss is inaudible.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, but as I mentioned in the question I have already tried this to no avail. It does not seem to be mic related as even muting mic input doesnt resolve the problem